# GWT adding Event Handler overrides the native one?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, event-handling

lets say i have the following html element on my host page:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.value = ''" id="textField"/>
```

In gwt i wrap this into an TextBox Widget like this:

```
final TextBox myTextBox = TextBox.wrap(DOM.getElementById("textField"));
```

If i now want to add a focus handler what will happen?

```
myTextBox.addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {

public void onFocus(final FocusEvent event) {
            // do something
        }
});
```

What i want to achieve is that first the javascript which was defined on the host page should be executed and after that my focus handler should be executed. But what actually is happening is that the javascript from the hostpage is not being executed and only the code within onFocus is executed. Is this behavoir normal? I would expect that add means actually add and not override. Is there a way to work arround this? Or do i maybe have any flaws which induce this behavoir. Any help is appreceated.

kuku

Comment: Not entirely sure but isn't there only one listener per event type for each element? This would mean the inline handler would be overwritten by the GWT 'traditional' handler which is added later. This may be helpful: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Comment: As a workaround: just add the inline handler also via GWT if that's possible.

Comment: The problem is i will wrap the input html element into an TextBox without knowing what handlers it has attached. My Widget however will add severall event handlers himself. So if it is true what your saying i have to check if the element has event handlers if it has and if i will override them i have to save the value of those handlers and add them to the handler i write. I don't know if thats possible but i will give it a try.